# Can't proceed to evaluate a conditon between two strings in Python (sikuli)

Tags: python, sikuli

I just want to compare an input value (here marqueUP) to some string.
I just can't make it happen since it always goes to the last option (the else).
Wehn I popup marqueUp, I have APPLE that appears so this looks fine.
I don't know what is wrong with my first condition to put 1 in the variable nbDeFois.

There is the code (I can't make the code indent properly here after the first line)

```
def DefinirMarque( marque ):
    marqueUP = marque.upper()
    nbDeFois = 0
    popup(marqueUP) #Result is APPLE
    if marqueUP == "APPLE":
        nbDeFois = 1
        popup("Je passe 1")
    elif marqueUP == "LG":
        nbDeFois = 5
        popup("Je passe 2")
    elif marqueUP == "SAMSUNG":
        nbDeFois = 8
        popup("Je passe 3")
    else:
        nbDeFois = 0
        popup("Je passe 4")
    click(find("1465009237647.png"))
    wait(0.5)
    KEYDOWN(nbDeFois)
```

The function that call DefinirMarque() is this one :

```
def CopierTitreEtDescription( directory ):

    for file in os.listdir(directory):
           if file.endswith(".txt"):
                   directoryTXT = directory + "\\" + file
    j = 0
    c = 0
    theFile = open(directoryTXT, 'r')
    for line in theFile:
        print line #copier la ligne en memoire
        if line.startswith("###"):
            click(find("1463792648668.png").right(30))
            prix = line.translate(None, "# ")
            paste(prix)
        elif line.startswith("##"):
            DefinirMarque(line.translate(None, "# "))            
        elif line.startswith("#"):
            DefinirFournisseur(line.translate(None, "# "))
        elif j < 2:
            click(Pattern("1465009088142.png").similar(0.93))
            paste(line)
            j = j + 1
        else:
            if c == 0:
                click(Pattern("1465009107116.png").similar(0.92)) 
                c = 1
            paste(line)
    theFile.close()
```

Comment: Please try again to indent properly as it is in your code. As indentation is not optional in python this may be the root of your problem so we might not be able to help you without seeing the exact same code as you have it in your file

Comment: Could you add complete code? What calls DefinirMarque()? Assuming proper indentation, that method looks fine. Though you're missing a colon after if marqueUP == "APPLE"

Comment: Code indentation can be done easily with StackOverflow's tools. Copy-paste your code, then select the code and select the "code" button. It will indent everything that is selected by 4 spaces.
Aside from that, are you sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in `margue`? We can't help you without more info about the parameters that you're passing in.

Comment: Indentation is now down, thank you for the explanation Oliver W.

Comment: @JeremyGordon

Code of the function that calls DefinirMarque() is there. With the popup, I am now sure that it correctly goes in DefinirMarque(). I can also say that it always popup "Je passe 4" which is the else.

One thing that'd be maybe nice to know is that the parameter "marque" is from a text fileé

Comment: Looks ok. You might be missing slight text mismatches in the popup(). Why not try stripping the string before comparison to make sure there is no trailing white space or new-lines. marqueUP = marque.upper().strip()

Comment: @JeremyGordon You sir, are awesome. It does work!
Thank you! I don't often code in Python so I don't really know the string functions.